# Docker image name is changed automatically

Tags: docker, docker-container

I've running several containers on my host (Ubuntu Server)

I ran docker container via a command, like below

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5050:80 gitname/reponame
```

And after I call `sudo docker ps` and it shows

```
CONTAINER ID: e404ffa2bc6b 
IMAGE: gitname/reponame 
COMMAND: "dotnet run --server…"
CREATED: 14 seconds ago
STATUS: Up 12 seconds
PORTS: 5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp
NAMES: reverent_mcnulty
```

And in a week I run `sudo docker ps` again and it shows another info where IMAGE was changed and it looks like ba2486f19dc0

I don't understand why.

It's problem for me because for stopping containers I use the command:

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | grep gitname/reponame |  awk '{print $1 }')
```

And it doesn't work because image name already was changed

Comment: In the meantime, have you run another `docker build` or `docker pull` that updates that image tag?

Comment: @DavidMaze no, I've just do docker pull from docker hub and run it, and also run another build from docker hub

Comment: You can add name to your container: `sudo docker run -d -p 5050:80 --name my_app gitname/reponame` and then use `docker stop my_app` `docker start my_app`

Comment: @quentino it'll change the name but no IMAGE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Docker image has a unique hex ID.  These IDs will be different on different systems (even `docker pull` of the same image), but every image has exactly one ID.

Each image has some number of tags associated with it.  This could be none, or multiple.  `docker tag` will add a tag to an existing image; `docker rmi` will remove a tag, and also (if there are no other tags on the image, no other images using the image as a base, and no extant containers using the image) remove the image.

It's possible to "steal" the tag from an existing image.  The most obvious way to do this is with `docker build`:

```sh
cat >Dockerfile <<EOF
FROM busybox
COPY file.txt /
EOF
echo foo > file.txt
docker build -t foo .

docker images
# note the ID for foo:latest

echo bar > file.txt
docker build -t foo .

docker images
# note the old ID will show as foo:<none>
# note a different ID for foo:latest
```

An explicit `docker tag` can do this too.  Images on Docker Hub and other repositories can change too (`ubuntu:16.04` is routinely re-published with security updates), and so if you `docker pull` an image you already have it can cause the old image to "lose its name" in favor of a newer version of that image.

How does this interact with `docker run` and `docker ps`?  `docker run` can remember the image tag an image was started with, but if the image no longer has that tag, it forgets that datum.  That's why your `docker ps` output reverts to showing the hex ID of the image.

There are a couple of ways around this for your application:

- If the image is one you're building yourself, always use an explicit version tag (could just be the current datestamp) both when building and running the image.  Then you'll never overwrite an existing image's tag.  ("Don't use `:latest` tags.")
- Use `docker run --name` to keep track of which container is which, and filter based on that, not the image tag.  (@quentino's suggestion from comments.)
- Don't explicitly `docker pull` in your workflow.  If you don't have an image, `docker run` will automatically pull it for you.  This will avoid existing images getting minor updates and also will avoid existing images losing their names.